# Fight club quote

Tags: grammar

> Marla-Tyler, you are the worst thing that ever happened to me.

I have asked question like this before but still I am confused in this sentence.

Why didn't she say

> You are the worst thing that ***has*** ever happened to me?

Comment: Note that people very often do not *say* things that are grammatical. It's somewhat meaningless to ask why somebody has *spoken* in a certain way—especially if you expect their diction to be accurate. I'm not saying that what she said here was wrong—just that even if it is wrong, people very often *are*. And in the context of actual dialogue, that's just fine. Informal verbal communication consists of more than just syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Because [**ellipsis**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/about-words-clauses-and-sentences/ellipsis).

> Ellipsis happens when we leave out (in other words, when we don’t use) items which we would normally expect to use in a sentence if we followed the grammatical rules

In other words, syntactical elements that are easily understood are often dropped in informal utterances. Understand? (Full version: Do you understand?)

While research papers and formal essays eschew such telescoping of syntax, ellipsis is a very common feature of informal conversation. You should get used to it, because if you ever do get to speak with native users of English you will certainly encounter it. A lot.

Answer (score 1):

Use of the perfect, especially in concert with **ever**, is not uniform among all native speakers.  There is considerable variation.  Some will use simple past, others the present perfect. That said, the meaning of that statement is:

> My life changed for the worse when we met. Nothing was worse for me than meeting you and getting involved with you.

The emphasis is on the past in that part of the statement, and on the present in "You are".  So the statement connects past to present in any case, and the present perfect is unnecessary to establish that meaning.

Comment: That is precisely what I am asking.to express relationship of past action with present ,we should use present perfect.and how is it unnecessary in this sentence?there are no word other than "are" to show the relationship.

Comment: Context and the word **are** are sufficient to establish that past-to-present relationship.